# Why is windows explorer very slow only on drive “E”?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, avi

I am having the following problem: each time I open windows explorer to go to my drive E: (to my downloads folder) and tries to open .avi files it takes ages to charge the file (looooong green loading bar in the address bar) and finally opens it...

I recently changed the hard-drive thinking my old one would have some defect. I gave to the new HD the same E: letter, I copied all of the old files on this new one for my programs and shortcuts to keep working.

But it happens AGAIN!

It only happens with the E: drive, none of my others HD are doing this. :/

I have :

- ASUS H87M-PLUS
- i5 4670
- 8 Gb DDR3
- GTX 660 TI 3Gb
- 128 Gb SSD Kingston (Win 7 x64)
- 640 Gb Samsung
- 2 x 1 Tb WD Blue (one of these is the E: drive)

Is it software or hardware or both? Any thoughts ?

This is what chkdsk E: gave me:

```
C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk E:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is Data.
WARNING! F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.
CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
251648 file records processed.
File verification completed.
0 large file records processed.
0 bad file records processed.
0 EA records processed.
0 reparse records processed.
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
305572 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
0 unindexed files scanned.
0 unindexed files recovered.
CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
251648 file SDs/SIDs processed.
Security descriptor verification completed.
26963 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
1529944 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.
Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.
976759807 KB total disk space.
389584228 KB in 223884 files.
97660 KB in 26964 indexes.
0 KB in bad sectors.
349039 KB in use by the system.
65536 KB occupied by the log file.
586728880 KB available on disk.
4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
244189951 total allocation units on disk.
146682220 allocation units available on disk.
```

Here is a PrtScreen of my [TaskManager right after starting W7](http://s27.postimg.org/4xzv0vrkj/Task_Manager.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Explorer scans the files you browse to extract metadata about the file. Unfortunately the scanning of these files can take longer than expected or even hang. The reason could be a corrupt avi or coding Windows doesn't expect. You can edit the registry so the Explorer doesn't do these scans anymore. The downside is you'll lose the metadata of new files to be scanned.

You can change the behavior in the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertyHandlers
```

There you'll find the property handlers for the specific file extensions.
You could rename `.avi` to `.avi-old`. It will stay there so you can easily change it back when you want to restore the scanning ability. You can do this for other file-types too (like `.mp4` to `.mp4-old`). I would only change this for the file-types you have problems with.

There is no way to change this on a folder by folder basis. It is system-wide.

There is one other thing you could try. You could try changing your folder-view to **list** (not details or small/large icons). *With any luck* Explorer won't try to scan the file **at that moment**. When in details-view it will try to scan because it needs to display the metadata. If you always want the date, size and type to display you can set it to details-view and try to change the default view for that folder to only display those properties (right-click folder, customize and set optimize folder for "General items") but this *is* a folder by folder setting. (But i'm not sure Explorer will still try to scan the metadata at that time, it's just trial and error)

Comment: Hello Rik, I wanted to let you know that the problem came back and not only on the E: drive, some videos are loading (green bar) others don't. In the same folder and regardless of the size... And in Safe Mode, ALL of them work fine !

Comment: @Clamp77 Did you check if that registry-entry didn't come back? Maybe with a Windows-update the settings were restored for .avi and .mp4. What extensions do the videos have that cause this problem? And what extensions don't cause this?

Comment: Nothing has change in the registry-entry, and I didn't accept any Windows update since then :). It happens with any type, .avi, .mp4 and even .mp3. In some folders of the same disk it doesn't happen though (with same folder properties!)

Comment: Could it be because of some process turning "behind" or any malware/spyware ? Even my AV (Ad-Aware) didn't find anything, neither did: Avast, Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool and SpyBot.

Comment: EDIT : Yay ! I got rid of it. Here is how: I downloaded a bunch of other malware/spyware/antivirus softwares (Cureit, Malwarebytes, F-Secure BlackLight, etc.); then I booted in SafeMode, restored the Registry-entry to default + fixed issues with Ccleander and then ran one after another every program I had. I got rid of many things and corrupted files, etc. Now everything runs fast and smoothly everywhere on all my HDD :)

Comment: @Clamp77 Yeah... keeping your installation clean is a necessity for keeping it running smoothly. I also use Malwarebytes and CCleaner. I often encounter (older) computers where the temporary directories are overflowing. After running CCleaner these computer usually run a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

You should check all your hardware drivers are up to date. And try defragmentation of the drive also; `.avi` files can be large and your system may be spending time pulling pieces of it from all over the disk, especially if you have used it for a long time, and direct copied your new hdd from your old one.

If you are using buffering for these type of files, you may want to shrink the buffer size.

Comment: Drivers are up to date and defrag didn't help me more here. The .avi files I try to open are only 230mb! Regarding buffer, nope :/